# One Drive JavaScript error

Tags: onedrive

I was able to get inside the OneDrive using the Javascript File Upload picker. However, when I hit save, the loading wheel never goes past the screen?

**I checked the console and it gave me this error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Function.t.exports.e._parseAADResponse (OneDrive.js:3)
    at Function.t.exports.e.parsePickerResponse (OneDrive.js:2)
    at window.onedriveReceiveMessage.window.onedriveReceiveMessage (OneDrive.js:2)
    at Function.t.exports.e._sendResponse (OneDrive.js:2)
    at Function.t.exports.e.handleRedirect (OneDrive.js:2)
    at Function.t.exports.e.onloadInit (OneDrive.js:2)
    at OneDrive.js:2
    at Object.i.2../Constants (OneDrive.js:2)
    at n (OneDrive.js:2)
    at e (OneDrive.js:2)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// One Drive API Script 
function launchSaveToOneDrive(){
//alert('okk');
var odOptions = {
     clientId: "(i put my client id here)",
     action: "save",
     sourceInputElementId: "fileUploadControl",
     sourceUri: "",
     fileName: "",
     openInNewWindow: true,
     advanced: {
    redirectUri: "(i put my redirect uri here and it's being loaded over https)"
  },
     success: function(files){},
     progress: function(p){},
     cancel: function(){},
     error: function(e){}
}
     OneDrive.save(odOptions);
}
</script>

<input id="fileUploadControl" name="fileUploadControl" type="file">
<button type="button" onClick="launchSaveToOneDrive()">Save to 
OneDrive</button>
```

Comment: hey, what's the url you saw the error? any query parameters?

Comment: This is what I get in the URL. and it's being loaded over https. I can send a screenshot of what it looks like if I'm not 100% clear. https://mywebsite/keylist.cfm#state=aad%5Fpicker

Comment: Whats also odd is when I load it over HTTP instead of HTTPS it gives me a different console error. "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with orgin https://www.mywebsite.com from accessing a cross-origin frame." But when I load it over HTTPS it gives me that split property string error. that website I put in there isn't a real website I'm just using a dummy example to tell you the error.